# How to update Element from JSON in JointJs

Tags: javascript, jointjs

is there any possibility to update an Element from JSON in JointJs?

I'm sending the JsonArray via `cellView.model.toJSON()` to the Server and manipulate the map. Is there any way to send the changed JsonArray back to the paper by calling something like `updateFromJson()` on the Element?

Comment: in jointJs we make change on model, not on view, but you can retrieve the view of an element with `element.findView(paper)` and update what you want !

Comment: @Anonymous0day Is it possible to update it with one go via Json?

Comment: Ho sorry i missed cellView. ***model*** .toJSON ! have you tried with `cellView.model.set(jsonData);` ?

Comment: @Anonymous0day Oh wow! It works! The API Documentation is really bad in JointJs. But thank you!

Comment: I have added an answer, to people who look for same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because behind JointJS there is [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/).

To update the model we just call `model.set(jsonData)`.

in your case :
`cellView.model.set(jsonData);`
should do the trick.

Comment: I actually used this `graph.getCell(id).set(arguments)`, but it should do the same.

Comment: Yes, because getCell(id) return a Backbone model !

Comment: I'm having a problem with this. As my model sets listeners in its constructor,  when JointJS loads its content from a JSON, the constructor is not called. Has anyone solved this in a cool way?